# is it a good idea to use "sudo bash -c" instead of "sudo" forever?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

1st of all, we are talking about Debian/Ubuntu OS only.

2nd of all, we are talking about a non-root user with sudo privilege only.

---

---

So question is,

Is there any occasion that can not use `sudo bash -c 'command'` but only `sudo command` ?

is it a good idea to use `sudo bash -c` instead of `sudo` forever?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has been asked on multiple sites: [is it a good idea to use “sudo bash -c” instead of “sudo” forever?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/666213/is-it-a-good-idea-to-use-sudo-bash-c-instead-of-sudo-forever)

Comment: @steeldriver  I'm sorry about that, I'm new to here,  I was so confused that which site my questions were supposed to belong to, it's always so hard to make a proper choice for me. but seems like I just got the "answer".

Comment: Also note this is a Ubuntu site, for Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (ie. https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) so your use of Debian pulled you off-tpoic for this site.  Many of us may *love* and *use* Debian, but you should remain within site guidelines (you maybe accessing this site using your Ubuntu SSO/signon, but it's a Stack Exchange site, so questions should not be asked on other SE sites)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `bash`, then `bash -c` runs the command with `bash`, and `sudo command` runs the command with your shell.

If you are using `bash`, then `bash -c` creates *another bash* for you to run your script in, which may actually cause problems regarding variables.

Try this example

```
S=2
echo $S
bash -c echo $S
```

You will get different output!

Comment: Thanks for your good example, just reminds me of the quote```"```, we usually use ```bash -c "echo $S" ``` with quote, and I actually get the same output in this case as well.

Comment: Well, not using the bash -c version won't do you any harm and it won't cause you the trouble of quoting, which, if you happen to forget, can cause disaster.

Comment: @ShuShang not sure what you are trying to describe, `-c` takes a 'command string' and, any following arguments will be assigned as positional parameters starting from `$0`, in this case, `$S` will become `$0` which is used as the name of the script, e.g., `bash -c nonexistent $S` will give you `2: line 1: nonexistent: command not found`.

Comment: @tmp in most cases, you should use single quotes, or `$S` will be expanded by the current shell before `bash -c` interprets the command string. A general construct could look something like: `bash -c 'echo "$@"' my-bash 1 2 3 4`.

Comment: @bac0n But I still don't know why, in this example above, only bash -c " echo $S " or bash -c " echo ' $S ' " or bash -c " echo " $S " " will work, get the same outputs as echo $S = 2 , that would be another question of mine, what's exactly the quotes of bash -c itselves for? Do they effect straightly the command inside of them?